# Mahler measure literature

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I am new to complex analysis and polynomials and I am looking for tutorials/books/articles for Mahler measure$$M(p((z))= \left|a_0\right| \prod\limits_{i=1}^d\max\{1,|\alpha_i|\}
 $$ of univariate polynomials and special polynomials like cyclotomic polynomials, polynomials over finite fields, the bounds of Mahler measure and its various relations to concepts like  entropy, efficient numerical estimation of Mahler measure and the like. Could someone kindly refer me to the related literature? I would be  highly obliged for the same.

Comment: the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler_measure) page has quite an extensive list of references; this is not what you need?

Comment: Each of the punctuation errors that I corrected in your question is something that I would take to be a typographical error, if not for the fact that you did it repeatedly. Take a look at what I did. Punctuation in English and in all European languages and in many other languages works that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the references at Wikipedia, see James McKee and Chris Smyth, Around the Unit Circle – Mahler Measure, Integer Matrices and Roots of Unity, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-80031-4 and Brunault, F., & Zudilin, W. (2020), Many Variations of Mahler Measures: A Lasting Symphony (Australian Mathematical Society Lecture Series), Cambridge University Press, doi:10.1017/9781108885553.

Here's a description of the second book, taken from the publisher's website:

The Mahler measure is a fascinating notion and an exciting topic in contemporary mathematics, interconnecting with subjects as diverse as number theory, analysis, arithmetic geometry, special functions and random walks. This friendly and concise introduction to the Mahler measure is a valuable resource for both graduate courses and self-study. It provides the reader with the necessary background material, before presenting the recent achievements and the remaining challenges in the field. The first part introduces the univariate Mahler measure and addresses Lehmer's question, and then discusses techniques of reducing multivariate measures to hypergeometric functions. The second part touches on the novelties of the subject, especially the relation with elliptic curves, modular forms and special values of L-functions. Finally, the Appendix presents the modern definition of motivic cohomology and regulator maps, as well as Deligne–Beilinson cohomology. The text includes many exercises to test comprehension and challenge readers of all abilities.